# R: correlation for a two dimensional set of data

Tags: r, statistics

I have two data files that are organized as tables of numbers and I want to compute the correlation between the two datasets. (The only unusual thing here is that my data is organized as  2-dimensional arrays instead of  lists.) I use `read.table` to read the files into tables `scores` and `dists`.

```
    cor.test(dists, scores, method="spearman")
Error in cor.test.default(dists, dists, method = "spearman") : 
  'x' must be a numeric vector
```

I think this is because of the 2d nature of my data but don't know how to go about correcting it.

Comment: Try `cor.test(unlist(dists), unlist(scores), method="spearman")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten your tables using `unlist`:

```
cor.test(unlist(dists), unlist(scores), method="spearman")
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. So there is no way to work with multiply-indexed sets of data in R?

Comment: @Reza I am not sure I know what you mean – of course you can work with higher-dimensional tables and arrays; I assumed in this case you explicitly wanted to ignore the structure in your data?